# How to make a layout occupy the entire screen in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin7

I am trying to add a background image to a view in Vaadin. Since the layout in that view occupies only 75% of the screen, the background image also is applied only to that limit. But I want it to be applied to the entire screen, but I don't know how to do it. When I used `setSizeFull()` method, it pushed the elements down to the bottom (some went below the screen level). My code is below. Please help me to do it correctly.

```
public HomeView()  //constructor
{   
    rootLayout.setStyleName("backgroundimage");
    setCompositionRoot(rootLayout);
    rootLayout.setDefaultComponentAlignment(Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
    rootLayout.setSpacing(true);
    rootLayout.setSizeFull();

    rootLayout.addComponent(recentIssues);
    recentIssues.setStyleName("custom-heading");
    recentIssues.setWidth("200px");

    rootLayout.addComponent(tableLayout);
    tableLayout.setWidth("100%");
    tableLayout.setHeight("100%");
    tableLayout.setSpacing(true);

    raisedByMeTable();
    assignedToMeTable();
}
```

Comment: `setMargin` vs `setSpacing`?

Comment: @Hannes I'm sorry, I don't get you